# My passport does not have exit stamp from South Africa. Will there be any issues to getting a visa or any repercussions when entering country

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps, south-africa

My passport was not stamped by immigration when returning to India from South Africa. I'm aware that South Africa stamps passport when they exit the country. My passport was not stamped for reasons I'm not sure of.

Will there be any issues when applying for a visa or re-entering the country?

My visa is of 15+ years old.

**UPDATE**

I will be applying for a visa and will keep this post updated.

Comment: I don't really know the answer, but make sure to keep hold of the boarding pass used to leave the country, if India stamps on entry, this is a good proof too

Comment: This also happened with me. What's your update please?

Comment: @NicoleGusha I got my visa and traveled to SA without any issues. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I applied for a visa multiple times and it got rejected for false reasons even though I was sponsored and had all my documents. The reasons they gave was "bank statement suspicious" or "flight reservations not verified" or the famous "purpose doubtful".

I tried contacting to the SA Embassy in Mumbai and after many calls they finally picked up. After talking to them they said they can't help and I need to contact VFS. And VFS kept telling me to contact the embassy. SMH its like no one wants to work!

I gave up but before I did I gave it one last try. I applied for an e-visa and waited like 45 days. The evisa applications goes directly to the embassy in South Africa and not to the embassy in your country. And after waiting for 45 days,

**Voilah!, I GOT MY VISA!**

Now going abroad with that visa was no issue and authority in SA at immigration didn't ask anything regarding the exit stamp or any questions out of the general.

Now a few reasons my application might of been rejected for (I can only assume why):

1. Bank statement suspicious - This might because I was not a salaried employee and had large transaction amounts
2. Flight reservations not verified - This could be because my dummy flight ticket might of expired before they could review my application.
3. Purpose doubtful - Well, your cover letter is not convincing or they just don't want to issue you a visa.

My advice is to apply for an evisa or a visa through a travel agent. Why travel agent you say? Cuz corruption is everywhere in India as well as in the SA consulate in Mumbai. So when applying through a travel agent he will ask for an extra Rs.5K which he will give as bribe to the embassy when applying. That is how someone I met on the plane got it he later told me.

All the best!