# My Passport doesn't have an exit stamp from South Africa. And am not a South African . the Passport is new will there be any issue entry other country

Tags: passport-stamps

i used the emergency travel document and My Passport doesn't have exit stamp. will there be any visa problem going to another country?

Comment: Can you explain the sequence of events here? You entered SA on a regular passport and lost it, then left on an emergency document? Or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My passport does not have exit stamp from South Africa. Will there be any issues to getting a visa or any repercussions when entering country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/177873/my-passport-does-not-have-exit-stamp-from-south-africa-will-there-be-any-issues)